# Encoding error while trying to save csv file to s3 bucket (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, character-encoding

I'm trying to save a csv file directly into a `S3` bucket. Howerver, since I didn't find a way to do that directly (without using `pandas` dataframe), I save it into a my local machine, upload it into `S3` then remove it from the local machine , here is what my code looks like:

```
data= [[None, u'https://aaa.com/p/cat.do?tags=|5555|4444|8888&zzz;A=3', u'00.00.00.000, 00.00.00.000', u'25359725', u'2018-03-06 18:01:18', u'DC01F54GH8D.aa201', None, 1814498434, 765651, u'2018-03-12 18:01:18', 168, 0, u'2018-03-12 18:32:08.428032'], [None, u'https://aaa.com/p/cat.do?tags=|5555|4444|8888&zzz;A=', u'00.00.00.000, 00.00.00.000', u'10707456', u'2018-03-06 18:01:02', u'76FD86AA.abd', None, 1814498440, 760960, u'2018-03-12 18:01:02', 168, 0, u'2018-03-12 18:32:08.805207']]

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
filename="#"+str(datetime.utcnow()).replace(" ","_").replace(":","")+".csv"
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
s3_resource.Object('my_bucket', filename).put(Body=open(filename, 'rb'))
os.remove(filename)
```

The data list mentioned above is just a small sample of the real data.
Unfortunately, this raised this error:

```
writer.writerows(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 152-153: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to change:

```
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
```

by

```
with open(filename, "wb", errors='ignore') as f:
```

But I got this:

```
'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Can I get some help with this encoding problem please ? and if any one knows a better way to save csv file into s3, please share your solution with us.

Many Thanks.

I'm using `python 2.7`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to **upload a file to S3 using boto3**, the easier method would be:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```